# Counting rows based on column values in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df

```
 Reads   Counts
 aaaa     10
 bbbb     20
 cccc     25
```

and so on.

I want to calculate the number of reads which exceed a certain value of counts and plot that. Example I want a data frame that looks like

```
 Counts>=       #reads with Counts>= 
  1              3
  2              3
  3              3
  11             2
  20             2
  21             1
```

and so on. Can you suggest how I can get such a dataframe and plot it.

Comment: Isn't this similar to the question you posted earlier

Comment: The earlier question was about cumulative frequency, this is the opposite

Comment: `nrow(df)` minus the thing you asked about in the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the levels you want to plot at...

```
cutoffs <- 1:30
```

... you could do something like:

```
data.frame(cutoff=cutoffs, num.above=Reduce("+", lapply(dat$Counts, ">=", cutoffs)))
#    cutoff num.above
# 1       1         3
# 2       2         3
# 3       3         3
# 4       4         3
# 5       5         3
# 6       6         3
# 7       7         3
# 8       8         3
# 9       9         3
# 10     10         3
# 11     11         2
# 12     12         2
# 13     13         2
# 14     14         2
# 15     15         2
# 16     16         2
# 17     17         2
# 18     18         2
# 19     19         2
# 20     20         2
# 21     21         1
# 22     22         1
# 23     23         1
# 24     24         1
# 25     25         1
# 26     26         0
# 27     27         0
# 28     28         0
# 29     29         0
# 30     30         0
```

Basically for each value in the original data frame you compute a vector of whether it's greater than or equal to each cutoff (using `lapply` with `>=`). Then you add them up (using `Reduce` with `+`), getting the total number greater than or equal to each cutoff.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be using `outer/colSums`

```
 cutoff <- 1:30 
 data.frame(cutoff=cutoffs, num.above=colSums(outer(df$Counts, cutoffs, ">=")))
```